# meeting in CDG & transferring to Orly

Tags: airport-transfer, planning, cdg, airport-terminals

3 friends and I will arrive at CDG on different flights from US (to terminals 2a & 2e).  We want to rendezvous at CDG somewhere & all transfer together to Orly for a separate flight on Air Corsica. We will have no checked bags. What would be the best place to meet for to all get to the Orly bus with the least time/trouble?

Comment: Who is arriving the earliest? Those landing in 2A or 2E?

Comment: Terminal 2A 7:45; Term. 2 E 8:15 and another Term 2A at 9:25.  We must then all transfer to Orly for a flight to Corsica leaving at 17:45.

Answer (score 4):

Since the last passenger arrives at terminal 2A the best thing to do would be to meet everyone at terminal 2A. What I would do is:

1. Friend 1 stays at terminal 2A arrivals in the area outside of baggage claim
2. Friend 2 transfers from terminal 2E to 2A arrivals; this takes ten minutes on foot
3. Friend 3 arrives at terminal 2A and finds the other two friends waiting for them outside of baggage claim

Whilst you all wait it might make sense to purchase the bus tickets to save some time. Once friend 3 arrives you can all go together to the [bus stop at gate C10](https://www.lebusdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plan-de-ligne-3.pdf).